# I have a user that every morning can not access her mapped drive. Until the drive is remapped and her AD password is reset. how do i fix this?

Tags: passwords, mapped-drive

This has been going on for a few weeks now every user in for this client has a mapped drive that corresponds with their user account. one user can not access her drive when she first comes in to get the issue resolved I have to delete and remap her drive then reset her password in AD. I reset her password to the same exact password every time.

I have created a batch file and attached it to startup that deletes her drive and remaps it automatically but i still have to reset her password.

I thought about blowing her AD user account out and recreating it but was not sure if this will fix it.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does the user have another PC that they can log into to see if the drive maps properly there? That way you can at least possibly narrow the issue down to the PC she's using instead of her AD account.

Comment: Does the user log in to _Windows_ using the same AD account, or does she use a local account for that?

Comment: The user logs in with her AD account not a local account. She does have another laptop and we have had her try login there and the same issue occurs.

Comment: Strange indeed... And you're sure it's only happening with this one user and not others from this client? Is the drive mapped to the user's home folder?

Comment: We have not go any other incidents where other users are having his issue, I have spoke to several of the other user and they are all reporting that they can access there shares without issue. yes, the drive is mapped to the users home folder.

Comment: I posted a reply/question yesterday that seems to have vanished overnight... Is the user connected on the same subnet as the other users who can access this shared drive?

Comment: @Didier i saw your your comment last night and replied and im not sure where it went. But yes she is on the same subnet as the other users.

Comment: It's something admins try to avoid, for many reasons, but if you try to logon using her username and a temp password, do you face the same issue?

Comment: I have not tried that yet i can give that a shot today.

Comment: using a temp password has no effect on this issue still occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-building the user profile in AD resolved the issue.